# CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, public

```
public struct Coordinate
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
}

Dictionary<float, List<Coordinate>> expected= new Dictionary<float, List<Coordinate>>
```

I want to do the unit test of the method that returns the result like this. The results are correct, but I am getting the error at *Element at 0 do not match*. I'm using **`CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual)`**

Comment: What are the values of each list.

Comment: What unit testing framework, NUnit?

Comment: I don’t think collectionassert works deeper to the list<Coordinate>, maybe you must implement an IEqualityComparer or something like that.

Comment: I have found a solution like this, but most definitely this ?
foreach(var item in expected.Keys)
{
 CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected[item], actual[item]);
}

Comment: would not be able to reproduce with the code you gave... could you extend it so we have a minimal, complete example?